# Auth0 Delegated Administration Extension

Tags: node.js, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am trying to use [Auth0 Delegated Administration Extension](https://github.com/auth0-extensions/auth0-delegated-administration-extension) in my app. For that, need to add a config file as below.

```
{
  "AUTHORIZE_API_KEY": "mysecret",
  "EXTENSION_SECRET": "mysecret",
  "WT_URL": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "AUTH0_DOMAIN": "me.auth0.com",
  "AUTH0_CLIENT_ID": "myclientid",
  "AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET": "myclientsecret",
  "EXTENSION_CLIENT_ID": "myotherclientid"
}
```

But I was unable to find values for `AUTHORIZE_API_KEY` and `EXTENSION_SECRET`

From where could I find those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are randomly generated values. Go ahead and generate something random using `crypto` and enter these there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: What is the `WT_URL`?

Comment: The public facing url. If you're running this on your machine, it should be the localhost url. Eg: http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Thanks for your reply